# Descending generic TObjectLIst

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

Say I have a base class:

```
  TPart = class
  private   
    FPartId: Integer;
  public
    property PartId: Integer read FPartId write FPartId;
  end;
```

and I have a generic list for this:

```
  TPartList = class(TObjectList<TPart>)
  public
    function IndexOfPart(PartId: Integer): Integer;
  end;
```

Now, if I descend from my TPart:

```
  TModulePart = class(TPart)
  private
    FQuantity: Integer;
  public
    property Quantity: Integer read FQuantity write FQuantity;
  end;
```

I want to now create a descendent of TPartList but be able to return me a TModulePart item.  Doing this:

```
  TModulePartList = class(TPartList)
  end;
```

will by default think that Items property is of type TPart and not TModulePart (naturally).  I don't want to do:

```
  TModulePartList = class(TObjectList<TModulePart>)
  end;
```

because then I miss out inheriting from common methods I might have in TPartList.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want like this:

```
TGenericPartList<T: TPart> = class(TObjectList<T>)
public
  function IndexOfPart(PartId: Integer): Integer;
end;
TPartList = TGenericPartList<TPart>;
TModulePartList = TGenericPartList<TModule>;
```

You can add even more flexibility if you design it like this:

```
TGenericPartList<T: TPart> = class(TObjectList<T>)
public
  function IndexOfPart(PartId: Integer): Integer;
end;
TPartList = TGenericPartList<TPart>;

TGenericModulePartList<T: TModule> = class(TGenericPartList<T>)
  procedure DoSomething(Module: T);
end;
TModulePartList = TGenericModulePartList<TModule>;
```